# Is there any canon material (of any level above fan-fic) which occurs post-finale in the BSG timeline?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

That is, is there any material which elucidates the specifics of what happened

> with the Galactica colony on actual Earth

after the

> ancient

events in the finale?

Comment: And before a smart-ass answers, I mean BEFORE the timeframe of the final seconds of the finale.

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica_(2004_TV_series)#Continuation) page cites an article from 2009 saying:

> On July 24, 2009, Edward James Olmos suggested that The Plan will not be the last BSG movie, saying that he had written a script involving the Galactica characters in which a crisis occurs at some point after their arrival on Earth.

However, that was nearly 8 years ago, and nothing has come out. All of the other material (comics, web mini series) deal with before the events of BSG, so there doesn't appear to be anything dealing with their time on Earth.

Comment: I'd like to read the script, even if it never gets produced.